# How to call a method, function or initialize class after an middleware in a controller constructor in Laravel and Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

How to call a method, function or initialize class after an middleware in a controller constructor in Laravel and Lumen?

I try initialize class `Translator` after `middleware('lang')`, but class `Translator` initialized before execute `middleware('lang')`.

**Controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller;
use App\Helpers\Translator;

class IndexController extends Controller
{

    private $transhome;

  
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('lang');
        $this->transhome = new Translator('home'); 
    }


    public function home()
    {
        return view('home', [
            'transhome' => $this->transhome,
        ]);
    }

}
```

**Middleware/LangMiddleware.php**

```
use Closure;

class LangMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        config(['app.lang' => 'fr']);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Another example**

After execution we will see: 132

`$this->middleware('lang');` the last will be called

**Controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo '1';
        $this->middleware('lang');
        echo '3';
    }


    public function home()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

}
```

**Middleware/LangMiddleware.php**

```
use Closure;

class LangMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        echo '2';

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not running a middleware with the `middleware` method, you are just setting an array index on the controller ... the controller is instantiated and the router asks it for what middleware it defines but it doesn't run them yet ... you would want to register a "controller middleware" (anonymous function) so that it will run as a middleware in the stack after the other one ... in Laravel at the least

Comment: @lagbox Do you mean? - `Controllers also allow you to register middleware using a closure.`? In not work: `$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
    return $next($request);
});` I get error - Illegal offset type

Comment: in Laravel you definitely can, I don't have a Lumen project setup to try it on

Comment: the other method would be to create a middleware that would assign this variable to your controller, in Laravel you can get the controller from the current route, from the request, and then you could assign the variable to the controller in the middleware ... again I don't have a Lumen project to test, as it does some things differently (uses a different router for example)

Comment: @lagbox In Laravel it works, but in Lumen no. ` $request->route()->controller;`

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this should work because you have the $transhome as `private` above. Try this with `public`.

It should work because in the constructor you tell it to set it to a translator.

Have you ever looked with `dd()` if transhome returns `null`?

Comment: Thanks, but `$this->middleware('lang')` called after `Translator`. If I replace `Translator` to `var_dump("222");` , the first execute is `var_dump ("222"); `.

Comment: I added another example.